# UIPickerView Font

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the font and/or color for individual UIPickerView Items?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. To do that you need to implement `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` method in picker's delegate - create `UILabel` instance there and setup it with whatever attributes you want.

Comment: Great, but how would you know the default Label attributes without guessing?

Answer (score 36):

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    UILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;
    if (!tView){
        tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            // Setup label properties - frame, font, colors etc
            ...
    }
    // Fill the label text here
    ...
    return tView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would simply go with attributed strings.

Implement this method is your delegate:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row
                      forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Comment: Tried this; didn't work (iOS 9.3), though it was getting called.

Comment: It worked for me with iOS 9.3.  Are you sure you are creating the NSAttributedString correctly?

Comment: I surely must have be doing something wrong, though I couldn't see what. In the end I did as suggested in the other answers and returned a configured label.