# How to change the font size in a UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIPickerView Font…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515528/uipickerview-font)

I'm really stuck on this one problem in my application. I searched everywhere to no avail. How can I change the font size in a UIPickerView?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Implement `viewForRow:forComponent:` method in picker's data delegate, create UILabel instance in it with the font (and all other properties) you need, e.g.:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    UILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;
    if (!tView){
        tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            // Setup label properties - frame, font, colors etc
            ...
    }
    // Fill the label text here
    ...
    return tView;
}
```

Comment: @Vladimir : It was really helpful added +1. But i have one question. Is is anything worry about HIG to do this customization?. Because i have show in your earlier answer which was in 2010. If there is anything than tell me please.

Comment: @Nit, don't think anything about UIPickerView has changed since then...

Comment: @Vladimir : ok thanks. I was also thinking same because it was in past. I just need some confirmation and that i got. Thanks really help full post for everyone. I want to add something If you don't mind.

Comment: @Nit, sure if you want to edit anyone answer with **useful** info feel free to do that - SO is community-driven site :) If you have a bit different issue it may be better to ask it as a separate question - long comment threads are really discouraged on SO

Comment: I think you should autorelease tView after allocatin & initializing.

Comment: @YunusNedimMehel, yes tView should indeed be autoreleased. but lets assume that everyone uses ARC now so the code above is ok

Answer (score -1):

PickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.4, 0.4);

Comment: -1 This makes the whole UIPickerView smaller